# Adding special information to a pharmacy order

Tags: practice-of-medicine

I'm interested to know if it is possible for a specific medicine to require that the pharmacist includes prescriber's identity is included on any orders.

If so, how does such an instruction get added to the medicine such that the pharmacy software would alert the pharmacy of the need?

The reason would be to do with early-access alerts.
The region I am currently interested is UK/EU - but the question is general.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What does the pharmacy need to be alerted about? And what are early-access alerts?

Comment: Downvoting because no explanation about the alert and early access are given. The OP had returned back here after being asked to explain.

Comment: Hi yes - I need to think how best to re-express the question.

Comment: I am not sure about UK/EU. I have been in the US and Asia. In every place I have been, the drug orders are always accompanied by the physician(prescriber)'s ID. I have never seen **any** exception. The reason is simple. What if the physician was wrong? The drug is supposed to take once daily, but the doc wrote twice daily? The dosage is supposed to be 2.5 mg, the doc says 25 mg? The pharmacist must know whom to call so the mistake can be corrected. Physicain's name is always in the system. **No exception.**. I really don't know what you are talking about ???

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you‘d like to know how the pharmacist and/or the software used in the pharmacy recognizes if a prescription drug requires the **physicians identity** to be transmitted during order.

As far as I know the drug regulation laws in EU countries vary significantly between the individual countries so I can speak only for the country I am residing in (Germany).

There are only very few specific cases of drugs which require the information of the prescribing physician to be submitted during order of the drug. Some of those include lenalidomide and/or thalidomide or specific programs for heroin rehab programs. But as I said before, the specific drugs this would apply to vary between countries.

So there is no general need to have a specific detection in place, as that process differs wildly from the usual process of ordering - for a ’general’ pharmacy this would be the pharmaceutical wholesale, where generally no identity of any physician is transmitted.

Comment: thanks for this., I will think further about what it is I am trying to ask.

Comment: you seem to be the person to ask on this:  On a 'general pharmacy' order to the wholesale, are the prescription Unique IDs recorded on the order against each medication?  For instance, if I am a pharmacist ordering Citalopram, am I required to put the corresponding prescription UUID into the order?

Comment: No, not in the jurisdiction I live in. I don‘t know about the rest of europe but I‘dd guess there would be no need for this and the complexity would serve no real purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.